# Write a log collector/reader, any good design?

Tags: c++, linux, logging

Given a directory, read all log files (in text) and send each line over network.

So the basic problem is to design a log reader, it needs to:

- 1, find log files in a directory
- 2, read unread log files
- 3, log files can be growing when read
- 4, log files can be moved to other places or deleted when reading
- 5, if log reader is down, continue where it stops when it starts up
  next time (no duplication and no loss)

Previously I use inode to record the progress and files read, but inode can be repeated.

So any good idea how to accomplish these goals?

Comment: do you know about inotify ? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html . It can help you to achieve 2,5 point. Btw, why exactly do u need a log reader when u have rsyslog ?

Comment: a previous design used inotify, and it used inode to track the new files and moved files and deleted files, but inode can be reused. inotify design does not solve 5, when the reader is down, the old file is deleted, and new file created, the inode does not change (and the name can be same).

Comment: can you tell why you need another log reader ? when you have so much other options like rsyslog, filebeat  ?

Comment: because we have another need: water mark of a log. say you want to collect logs from different boxes, their log event time can be different, and when you collected them at the server side, the consumer (e.g. some work needs to know if you have collected all logs since xxx timestamp to start), the 'water mark' feature is needed and it's done in the log reader and with other server infra.

Comment: Here is what I think. Whatever you desgin, you have to give them the path of the all the log files to them to read files. I think it is not a good idea to give a complete directory to log reader and make it fetch all the files in it. I have successfully used rsyslog to push all logs to elasticsearch( with timestamp ) from different servers.

Comment: and moreover, designing and building from scratch will be a time consuming and not a reliable thing to do. The already present tools are realiable, secure, fast and have a large community support. And I think they can do pretty much everything you need to do with logs.

Comment: yes, we need to design a log collector from scratch. we have over 500k boxes to managed and they need a good solution, i.e. the configuration can be dynamically set by a lot of complex rules, the collector needs to support progress and watermark management. Reader is just a part of it and I'd like to have a good idea how to keep tracking of the files.

Answer (score -2):

You want standard log collector...
use `syslog-ng` or something like this.
https://syslog-ng.org/

Or if you want write one, check the code of syslog-ng... :P